# VBA Excel select a range of cells within a named range

Tags: vba, excel, named-ranges

I have a Named Range `col_9395` it is an entire column.  I want to set a range within this Named range.  I want the range to start at row 3 to row 200 of same column.  Whats the best way to do this?

Original working line without Named Range:

```
Set rngBlnk = Sheet108.Range("T3:T200").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
```

This is the code I tried with no luck:

```
Set rngBlnk = Range("col_9395)(3,1):Range("col_9395)(200,1).SpecialCells (xlCellTypeBlanks)
```

Comment: There are many ways to do it. Best way is using `Resize` function on range. Its there for this purpose only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be wrong, but I find this the easiest one:

```
Private Sub Test()
    Dim rngBlnk As Range
    Set rngBlnk = Range("col_9395").Rows("3:200").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks.  This worked like a charm.  I knew I was missing something simple

Answer (score 1):

You can see the sort of logic with

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim colToUse As Long
colToUse = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("ol_9395").Column

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Debug.Print .Range(.Cells(3, colToUse), .Cells(200, colToUse)).Address
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub t()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("col_9395") ' for easier use

Dim blnkRng As Range
Set blnkRng = Range(Cells(rng.Rows(3).Row, rng.Column), Cells(rng.Rows(200).Row, rng.Column)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
blnkRng.Select
End Sub
```

What I did was assign your named range to a variable (just for easier referencing). Then using the `Range()` property, I used the `3rd` and `200th` row of your named range to set the range to look for blank cells.

The idea is that this will help you in the event your named range isn't simply an entire column.  It will get the relative 3rd and 200th row from your named range.

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim rngBlnk As Range

    Dim firstCell As Range
    Dim lastCell As Range

    Set firstCell = [col_9395].Cells(3, 1)
    Set lastCell = [col_9395].Cells(200, 1)

    If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Range(firstCell, lastCell)) > 0 Then
        Set rngBlnk = Range(firstCell, lastCell).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    End If   

End Sub
```

A kind of a problem with `SpecialCells` and assigning to them is that if there are no cells from the specific type, it throws an error.

Thus, there is a check with `WorksheetFunction.CountBlank()>0`, before the setting of `rngBlnk` to the special cells.

Comment: Woah! I like the way you did the first and last cell.  I didn't know you could use the evaluate brackets to reference a named range like that. (I assume since it's in the 'evaluate' brackets, you don't need `["col_9395"]`?) It's much easier to read than my answer. Clever, and thanks for teaching me something :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, I know, but maybe this will help someone.  I've stumbled on a technique that I don't see presented as an option in any of the handful of "range-in-a-range" questions here.

I discovered you can ask VBA for a range of a range directly.  I have formatted some data as a Table, but it could be simply a Named Range, or even an unnamed range I suppose.  My code that is working looks like this:

```
        With Workbooks(Filename)
            .Worksheets(tabName).Activate
            .Worksheets(tabName).Range("SummaryBand").Range("B2:R2").Copy
            End With
```

My Table is named SummaryBand, which due to a previous step was not necessarily always in the same absolute position on the spreadsheet, but I wanted an absolute Range within SummaryBand.  In this example, "B2:R2" is the absolute position within the Table, with the top left cell of the Table being A1.